# Ionic 4 Capacitor Choose file for Android and IOS

Tags: ionic4, capacitor

I was developing an app in ionic 4 using Capacitor for android and IOS. I can't find any way to choose a file using Capacitor's api. I had looked for method in the Capacitor's "Filesystem" api (https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/filesystem/) but could not find any that would allow me th choose file. Is there any other way I can choose file from android or IOS device using ionic 4 with Capacitor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an input with type file

`<input type="file" name="myFile">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin I've developed:
https://github.com/hinddeep/capacitor-file-selector

1. Allows the developer to specify whether the user can select single or multiple files
2. Lends the ability to restrict the user to select files conforming to a given set of extensions
3. Lends the ability to restrict the user to select files conforming to a broader category of multimedia files, i.e. Audios, Videos and Images
4. Supported Platforms: Android (is compatible with Android 10+'s scoped storage), iOS and Web

Comment: Try to answer the question stated, not just advertise your project.